# char.isnumber('.') returns false on "en-US" locale

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making windows forms application that works with g-code.
basically inputs are strings that may look like this:

> X32.2Y47Z100.5

In order to retrieve each numbers first i have to find out how long is the individual substring representing the number.

in my load event I have these:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

after these lines the locale itself has value "en-US"
yet both of the following returns false.

```
char.IsNumber('.');
char.IsNumber(',');
```

also convert.toDouble() fails when string contains either '.' or ','.

Comment: Why would you expect it to return true?

Comment: What number do you expect `.` or `,` to represent?

Comment: Also, you should be using double.Parse or TryParse instead of Convert.ToDouble

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: I think this *is* a case for regex

Comment: You know the first character is X (assuming these are always X,Y & Z coordinates. It should be simple to substring out the numeric information using IndexOf with Substring or with a RegularExpression.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are expecting the characters `.` and `,` to be considered numbers, when they aren't. They are only considered part of a valid number when used with actual numbers, and then only if their placement is correct according to the current culture.

You can split the string on the x, y, and z characters, either by using `RegEx` or by the `string.Split` method, and then you can use `double.TryParse` to convert the split parts into doubles:

```
private static void Main()
{
    string input = "X32.2Y47Z100.5";

    string[] inputParts = input.Split(new[] {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (inputParts.Length == 3)
    {
        double x, y, z;
        double.TryParse(inputParts[0], out x);
        double.TryParse(inputParts[1], out y);
        double.TryParse(inputParts[2], out z);
        Console.WriteLine($"The values are: x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input was not in a valid format.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Regex, to replace all letters with ";"

   ```
   Regex.Replace(YourInputString, "[^0-9.,]", ";")
   ```
2. Split the result with ";"

   ```
   var YourInputStringArray = YourInputString.Split(';')
   ```
3. Remove all empty entries

   ```
   YourInputStringArray =  YourInputStringArray .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
   ```
4. Convert it to double

   ```
   foreach(var inputString in YourInputStringArray)
   {
      if(double.TryParse(inputString, out var result)){
          // Here is your double value
      }
   }
   ```